# Odoo Partner Ledger Report Customization

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-15

I need to customize the view of the *Partner Ledger Report* in Odoo 15 (from Accounting -> Reporting -> Partner Ledger) but I can't find the detailed view.

It seems very dynamic and it appears to get built during runtime.

I couldn't find it in (Settings -> Technical -> Reports).

**How can I customize the view of this report or even change it from PDF to HTML?**

Comment: The accounting reports are not available in Odoo Community. Are you using Odoo Enterprise or Odoo community with custom module for accounting reports?

Comment: I'm using the Enterprise version

Comment: Accounting reports in Odoo 15 Enterprise is not opened as PDF, it's open as HTML using client action.  You can find report template in account_reports module with this name ```line_template_partner_ledger_report```